# Codeigniter 4 - How to route with .php suffix without using it as default

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, routes, suffix

I'm currently rewriting an existing website. I need to route some old links to the new corresponding sites. The old url uses the .php suffix and I can't figure out how to route this properly with codeingiter 4.

For example the link would be `www.example.com/lang/something.php` which I want to redirect or route to a specific controller.

I tried the following, which didn't worked, as it doesn't seem to match the .php part.

```
$routes->get('/lang/something.php', "Something::show/something");
```

I'm using Codeigniter 4. I have read about the allowed_suffixes option in CI 3 but couldn't find it for CI 4 and in general I only want to use this suffix for this particular old link. In general I don't want to use any url suffixes.

Thanks!

Comment: did you look into [Redirecting Routes](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html?highlight=routes#redirecting-routes) ?

Comment: It's the same. The suffix seems to be the problem.

Comment: seriously - how do the developers overlook and just leave this out - when thousands are using it in version 3.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to edit the htaccess file in the public folder. I added

`Redirect 301 /lang/something.php https://example.com/lang/something`

at the beginning of the file. So the request is redirected to an url pattern that can be routed with CI. The routing rule just stays the same but without the suffix:

`$routes->get('/lang/something', "Something::show/something");`

However, I have not found a way to match the suffix with CI4. Maybe someone will find this helpful.